# Detachable Tabs in Qt5+

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am looking to make a detachable/re attachable tab, much like how you can in Google Chrome. Does anyone know if this is possible in Qt 5+?

Answer (score 3):

Up to Qt 5.3 it doesn't support detachable tabs and for this you would need to implement your own widget.

The closest thing you can get from standard Qt Widgets are docked `QDockWidget`s but I don't recommend it:

[image]